# logOut SyncUser on Realm in Swift

Tags: realm, swift3

*RealmSwift 2.0.2, Realm Object Server 1.0, Swift 3*

I'm unsure how to sign out the current user in Realm. I've tried:

```
SyncUser.logOut()
```

...but I get this error:

> User of instance member ‘logOut’ on type ‘RLMSyncUser’; did you mean
>   to use a value of type ‘RLMSyncUser’ instead?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`logOut()` is an instance method on `SyncUser`, not a class method. Try:

```
myUser.logOut()
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I needed to get the instance of the current user first:

```
let user = SyncUser.all().first
user?.logOut()
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is:

```
SyncUser.current?.logOut()
```